# Uninitialized constant AssetSync

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, assets

I used the gem asset_sync and aws to precompile my assets. rake assets:precompile works fine. After I pushed my app to heroku, and

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error

> "uninitialized constant AssetSync"

initializers/asset_sync.rb

```
AssetSync.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'AWS'
  config.aws_access_key_id = "..."
  config.aws_secret_access_key = "..."
  config.fog_directory = Rails.env + "-..."
  config.fog_region = 'eu-west-1'
end
```

config/production.rb

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
config.assets.enabled = true
```

After running run rake assets:precompile the first time, all my app/assets/images were moved to public/assets . I've deleted them from github and added public/assets/* to .gitignore. May this be the problem?

Edit: when running git push heroku master, it looks like they were precompiled

```
   Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   AssetSync: using /tmp/build_2ltvklj0gaxjp/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
   AssetSync: using /tmp/build_2ltvklj0gaxjp/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
   AssetSync: Syncing.
   Using: Directory Search of /tmp/build_2ltvklj0gaxjp/public/assets
   Uploading: assets/application-7e17d9f0ed9cb7ea50b750e2bfc7e28c.css.gz
   Uploading: assets/application-7e17d9f0ed9cb7ea50b750e2bfc7e28c.css
   AssetSync: Done.
   Asset precompilation completed (58.04s)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your initializer assumes that AssetSync is always defined, but this will not be the case if your `Gemfile` looks like:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'asset_sync'
end
```

The `asset_sync` documentation recommends wrapping the initializer in:

```
if defined?(AssetSync)
...
end
```

This is because Heroku runs `production` without the `assets` group of gems. Heroku precompiles your assets when you run a push -- and if `asset_sync` is enabled, it will update S3 at that time -- so when your application launches later, it no longer needs those gems. Thus, your `asset_sync` initializer needs to handle the situation where the gem is not loaded.